# Laravel workbench composer update

Tags: laravel, composer-php, reload

I added to my composer.json the following line inside of my workbench but dosn't take any effect the controllers are not mapped? How do I republish or reload the composer.json

```
"autoload": {
     "classmap": [
        "src/controllers"
    ],
}
```

I already tried

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `composer update` inside your workbench